# nginx and php-fpm in Docker problems

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I thought that this would a simple project - but it seems that getting my website into Docker is more complicated than I anticipated!  There are a few symptoms - but I suspect that it might all boil down to one problem - the php configuration.

Oh - there is one other problem.  I've been hacking around to find the correct magic spell, but my hacking has been with minimal notes (but I have been taking periodic backups).

Initially the issue was that a website could be loaded using html - but attempting to load a php file just caused that php file to be downloaded.

I fixed that issue only to be greeted with the white screen of death when trying to load a php file (this is one of the configurations that I have backed up!).  Sadly, this 'success' also brought with it the problem that any attempt to load the website without appending 'index.html' caused an error -

```
rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "////////////"
```

I fiddled a bit more to try to solve the problem - and now I get **500 Internal Server Error** whenever I try to load a website.  Ever wish that you hadn't started something?

Sadly (and strangely) the error persists even after restoring all the original configuration.  If anyone has any cunning ideas for fixing this mess, I'd love to hear them!

*docker-compose.yml*

```
web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
        - '80:80'
        - '443:443'
    links:
        - phpfpm
    volumes:
        - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
        - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        - ./nginx/fastcgi.conf:/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf
        - ./nginx/sites-available:/etc/nginx/sites-available
        - ./nginx/sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled                  
        - ./public:/var/www
phpfpm:
    image: 'bitnami/php-fpm'
    ports:
        - '9000:9000'
    volumes:
        - ./public:/var/www
    working_dir: /var/www
mysql:
    image: 'mariadb'
    ports:
        - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
        - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=notgivingoutmypassword
```

*nginx.conf*

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
include    /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    multi_accept on;
}


http {
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 10 10;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 4096k;
    client_header_timeout 10;
    client_body_timeout 10;
    send_timeout 10;

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

        # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

*mywebsite.conf* (in sites_available)

```
upstream php {
        server phpfpm:9000;
}

server {
        server_name  www.mywebsite.com;
        server_tokens off;

        error_log "/var/log/nginx/mywebsite-error.log";
        access_log  "/var/log/nginx/mywebsite-access.log";

        location / {
                root   /var/www/mywebsite/htdocs;
                index  index.php index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ { 
                include fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass php;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

*fastcgi.conf*

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

*php-fpm.conf*

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; FPM Configuration ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; All relative paths in this configuration file are relative to PHP's install
; prefix (/opt/bitnami/php). This prefix can be dynamically changed by using the
; '-p' argument from the command line.

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Global Options ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[global]
; Pid file
; Note: the default prefix is /opt/bitnami/php/var
; Default Value: none
;pid = run/php-fpm.pid

; Error log file
; If it's set to "syslog", log is sent to syslogd instead of being written
; into a local file.
; Note: the default prefix is /opt/bitnami/php/var
; Default Value: log/php-fpm.log
error_log = /opt/bitnami/php/logs/php-fpm.log

; syslog_facility is used to specify what type of program is logging the
; message. This lets syslogd specify that messages from different facilities
; will be handled differently.
; See syslog(3) for possible values (ex daemon equiv LOG_DAEMON)
; Default Value: daemon
;syslog.facility = daemon

; syslog_ident is prepended to every message. If you have multiple FPM
; instances running on the same server, you can change the default value
; which must suit common needs.
; Default Value: php-fpm
;syslog.ident = php-fpm

; Log level
; Possible Values: alert, error, warning, notice, debug
; Default Value: notice
log_level = warning

; If this number of child processes exit with SIGSEGV or SIGBUS within the time
; interval set by emergency_restart_interval then FPM will restart. A value
; of '0' means 'Off'.
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_threshold = 0

; Interval of time used by emergency_restart_interval to determine when
; a graceful restart will be initiated.  This can be useful to work around
; accidental corruptions in an accelerator's shared memory.
; Available Units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_interval = 0

; Time limit for child processes to wait for a reaction on signals from master.
; Available units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;process_control_timeout = 0

; The maximum number of processes FPM will fork. This has been designed to control
; the global number of processes when using dynamic PM within a lot of pools.
; Use it with caution.
; Note: A value of 0 indicates no limit
; Default Value: 0
; process.max = 128

; Specify the nice(2) priority to apply to the master process (only if set)
; The value can vary from -19 (highest priority) to 20 (lowest priority)
; Note: - It will only work if the FPM master process is launched as root
;       - The pool process will inherit the master process priority
;         unless specified otherwise
; Default Value: no set
; process.priority = -19

; Send FPM to background. Set to 'no' to keep FPM in foreground for debugging.
; Default Value: yes
;daemonize = yes

; Set open file descriptor rlimit for the master process.
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_files = 1024

; Set max core size rlimit for the master process.
; Possible Values: 'unlimited' or an integer greater or equal to 0
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_core = 0

; Specify the event mechanism FPM will use. The following is available:
; - select     (any POSIX os)
; - poll       (any POSIX os)
; - epoll      (linux >= 2.5.44)
; - kqueue     (FreeBSD >= 4.1, OpenBSD >= 2.9, NetBSD >= 2.0)
; - /dev/poll  (Solaris >= 7)
; - port       (Solaris >= 10)
; Default Value: not set (auto detection)
;events.mechanism = epoll

; When FPM is built with systemd integration, specify the interval,
; in seconds, between health report notification to systemd.
; Set to 0 to disable.
; Available Units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default value: 10
;systemd_interval = 10

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Pool Definitions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Multiple pools of child processes may be started with different listening
; ports and different management options.  The name of the pool will be
; used in logs and stats. There is no limitation on the number of pools which
; FPM can handle. Your system will tell you anyway :)

; Include one or more files. If glob(3) exists, it is used to include a bunch of
; files from a glob(3) pattern. This directive can be used everywhere in the
; file.
; Relative path can also be used. They will be prefixed by:
;  - the global prefix if it's been set (-p argument)
;  - /opt/bitnami/php otherwise
include=/opt/bitnami/php/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf
```

The error files contain the following problems:

*error.log*

```
2018/02/08 15:46:38 [emerg] 1#1: upstream "php" may not have port 9000 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mywebsite.conf:24
2018/02/08 16:47:02 [emerg] 1#1: upstream "php" may not have port 9000 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mywebsite.conf:24
```

(I've checked the php configuration - it is configured to listen on port 9000.  As you can see from the yml, that appears to be correctly configured too)

Each attempt to connect is correctly logged in *mywebsite-access.log* so I'm not going to paste it in verbatim here.

*mywebsite-error.log*

```
2018/02/08 17:03:06 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:03:06 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs//" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:03:06 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs///" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:03:06 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs////" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:03:06 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/////" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:03:06 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs//////" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:03:06 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs///////" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:03:06 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs////////" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:03:06 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/////////" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:03:06 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs//////////" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:03:06 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs///////////" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:03:06 [error] 5#5: *4 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "////////////", client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:39:50 [crit] 5#5: *1 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:39:50 [crit] 5#5: *1 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:39:53 [crit] 5#5: *1 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:39:53 [crit] 5#5: *1 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:39:55 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:39:55 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:39:56 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:39:56 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:39:58 [crit] 5#5: *1 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:39:58 [crit] 5#5: *1 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:41:43 [crit] 5#5: *1 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:41:43 [crit] 5#5: *1 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:41:43 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:41:43 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:41:47 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:41:47 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:41:47 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:41:47 [crit] 5#5: *4 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:41:48 [crit] 5#5: *1 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:41:48 [crit] 5#5: *1 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:41:55 [crit] 5#5: *1 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/indejx.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET /indejx.html HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:41:55 [crit] 5#5: *1 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/indejx.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET /indejx.html HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:41:57 [crit] 5#5: *1 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/indejx.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET /indejx.html HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
2018/02/08 17:41:57 [crit] 5#5: *1 stat() "/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/indejx.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 88.202.149.194, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET /indejx.html HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mywebsite.com"
```

The permission denied errors look promising - but the permissions on the directory (and all subdirectories) for the site are:

```
drwxrwxr--  4 www-data     www-data     4096 Feb  8 14:58 .
drwxrwxr-x 13 headbanger   headbanger   4096 Feb  8 16:54 ..
drwxrwxr--  2 www-data     www-data     4096 Feb  8 14:58 default
drwxrwxr--  3 www-data     www-data     4096 Feb  8 14:58 mywebsite
```

As always, all help gratefully received. This is really baking my noodle!

Comment: You might be onto something - but could you explain as if for a dullard (me, in fact!)

Comment: Can you include the contents of `fastcgi.conf` as well as your `php-fpm.ini`?

Comment: In your nignx config you have `default_type  application/octet-stream;` it was probably set when you displayed php files so thats why they were downloaded

Comment: I've added my php-fpm.conf (just in case it helps) but there isn't room for the ini file I'm afraid.